# Multiple objects somehow interfering with each other

Tags: python, oop, neural-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple objects somehow interfering with each other [original version]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262716/multiple-objects-somehow-interfering-with-each-other-original-version)

*(NOTE: I posted a similar question a few hours ago but it was poorly worded and explained, so this is a clearer resubmission)*

Hello,

I have a neural network (NN) which works perfectly when applied to a single data set. However if I want to run the NN on, for example, one set of data and then create a new instance of the NN to run on different set of data (or even the same set again) then the new instance will produce completely incorrect predictions.

For example, training on an XOR pattern:

```
    test=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
    data = [[[0,0], [0]],[[0,1], [0]],[[1,0], [0]],[[1,1], [1]]]

    n = NN(2, 3, 1) # Create a neural network with 2 input, 3 hidden and 1 output nodes
    n.train(data,500,0.5,0) # Train it for 500 iterations with learning rate 0.5 and momentum 0

    prediction = np.zeros((len(test)))
    for row in range(len(test)):
        prediction[row] = n.runNetwork(test[row])[0]

    print prediction

    #
    # Now do the same thing again but with a new instance and new version of the data.
    #

    test2=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
    data2 = [[[0,0], [0]],[[0,1], [0]],[[1,0], [0]],[[1,1], [1]]]

    p = NN(2, 3, 1)
    p.train(data2,500,0.5,0)

    prediction2 = np.zeros((len(test2)))
    for row in range(len(test2)):
        prediction2[row] = p.runNetwork(test2[row])[0]

    print prediction2
```

Will output:

```
    [-0.01 -0.   -0.06  0.97]
    [ 0.  0.  1.  1.]
```

Notice that the first prediction is quite good where as the second is completely wrong, and I can't see anything wrong with the class:

```
    import math
    import random
    import itertools
    import numpy as np

    random.seed(0)

    def rand(a, b):
        return (b-a)*random.random() + a

    def sigmoid(x):
        return math.tanh(x)

    def dsigmoid(y):
        return 1.0 - y**2

    class NN:
        def __init__(self, ni, nh, no):
            # number of input, hidden, and output nodes
            self.ni = ni + 1 # +1 for bias node
            self.nh = nh + 1
            self.no = no

            # activations for nodes
            self.ai = [1.0]*self.ni
            self.ah = [1.0]*self.nh
            self.ao = [1.0]*self.no

            # create weights (rows=number of features, columns=number of processing nodes)
            self.wi = np.zeros((self.ni, self.nh))
            self.wo = np.zeros((self.nh, self.no))
            # set them to random vaules
            for i in range(self.ni):
                for j in range(self.nh):
                    self.wi[i][j] = rand(-5, 5)
            for j in range(self.nh):
                for k in range(self.no):
                    self.wo[j][k] = rand(-5, 5)

            # last change in weights for momentum   
            self.ci = np.zeros((self.ni, self.nh))
            self.co = np.zeros((self.nh, self.no))


        def runNetwork(self, inputs):
            if len(inputs) != self.ni-1:
                raise ValueError('wrong number of inputs')

            # input activations
            for i in range(self.ni-1):
                #self.ai[i] = sigmoid(inputs[i])
                self.ai[i] = inputs[i]

            # hidden activations   
            for j in range(self.nh-1):
                sum = 0.0
                for i in range(self.ni):
                    sum = sum + self.ai[i] * self.wi[i][j]
                self.ah[j] = sigmoid(sum)

            # output activations
            for k in range(self.no):
                sum = 0.0
                for j in range(self.nh):
                    sum = sum + self.ah[j] * self.wo[j][k]
                self.ao[k] = sigmoid(sum)

            ao_simplified = [round(a,2) for a in self.ao[:]]
            return ao_simplified  


        def backPropagate(self, targets, N, M):
            if len(targets) != self.no:
                raise ValueError('wrong number of target values')

            # calculate error terms for output
            output_deltas = [0.0] * self.no
            for k in range(self.no):
                error = targets[k]-self.ao[k]
                output_deltas[k] = dsigmoid(self.ao[k]) * error

            # calculate error terms for hidden
            hidden_deltas = [0.0] * self.nh
            for j in range(self.nh):
                error = 0.0
                for k in range(self.no):
                    error = error + output_deltas[k]*self.wo[j][k]
                hidden_deltas[j] = dsigmoid(self.ah[j]) * error

            # update output weights
            for j in range(self.nh):
                for k in range(self.no):
                    change = output_deltas[k]*self.ah[j]
                    self.wo[j][k] = self.wo[j][k] + N*change + M*self.co[j][k]
                    self.co[j][k] = change
                    #print N*change, M*self.co[j][k]

            # update input weights
            for i in range(self.ni):
                for j in range(self.nh):
                    change = hidden_deltas[j]*self.ai[i]
                    self.wi[i][j] = self.wi[i][j] + N*change + M*self.ci[i][j]
                    self.ci[i][j] = change

            # calculate error
            error = 0.0
            for k in range(len(targets)):
                error = error + 0.5*(targets[k]-self.ao[k])**2
            return error

        def train(self, patterns, iterations=1000, N=0.5, M=0.1):
            # N: learning rate
            # M: momentum factor
            for i in range(iterations):
                error = 0.0
                for p in patterns:
                    inputs = p[0]
                    targets = p[1]
                    self.runNetwork(inputs)
                    error = error + self.backPropagate(targets, N, M)
                if i % 100 == 0: # Prints error every 100 iterations
                    print('error %-.5f' % error)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that you can *edit* questions to clarify things.

Comment: You should have edited your original. Not asked the same question again. Even if clarified. I assume that [this is the previous one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262716/creating-multiple-instances-of-a-neural-network-class-causes-errors-but-a-singl).

Comment: Yes but because of the poor wording it was buried with no useful replies so editing wouldn't have helped.

Comment: Editing will bump your question. Now you've asked a duplicate. One of the two needs to be closed. Usually it will be the one you asked last (this one).

Comment: okay. Seems I've committed a terrible sin. I'll edit the first question so you can all keep your hats on!

Comment: In an unrelated (or maybe not) issue: this is Python, no need to make auxiliar functions for every basic thing you need: use the `random.uniform` function, instead of declaring your own `rand` function there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is clearly visible there is that you are seeding random to 0 -
I don't know enough abut your problem domaind to know if that s iyour intention - but doing this will always yield the same series of numbers, one after the other. The numbers are pseudo-random.

When you use a second instance of the same class, since the random seeding is in the module code, the series is not reset - and you run with the continuation of that series of pseuo-random numbers, not the same numbers. That could lead to different results on a second run 
if our algorithm does not actually work with random numbers, but depends on the specific series made available b random.seed(0)

Other than that, your code does not seem to keep any state out of the instance object that could result in the problems you describe.

In time - if your things should really work with random numbers, I propose ditching the random.seed statement at module level.

Otherwise, if the algorithm is correct and do depend on the sequence yielded after a random.seed(0), you just have to re-issue this statement before start working in the second instance of your network